Small examples of non-transitive Automorphism groups of Steiner Systems
I'm currently doing research for a bachelor's seminar talk.
I have found a result from E. Mendelsohn, "On the groups of automorphisms of Steiner triple and quadruple systems" stating that for any finite group G there exists a Steiner Triple System (S(2,3,n)) U such that G $\simeq$ Aut(U).
I know that some special finite groups are transitive or even k-transitive.
Like for example the Mathieu group $M_{24}$ which is 5-transitive "on" the Steiner System S(5,8,24) or maybe more precicely on the set $\{1,2,\dots,24\}$ and is $\simeq$ Aut(S(5,8,24)).
Other groups like $PSL((2,7)\simeq Aut(S(2,3,7))$ are also t-transitive for S(t,k,n)
(For PSL(2,7) in particular is even 3-transitive as $PSL(2,7)\simeq GL(3,2)$)
So as all finite groups are $\simeq Aut(S(2,3,n)$ for some n, but not all groups are transitive or even 2-transitive as a permutation group over $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, there should exist finite groups which are $\simeq Aut(S(2,3,n)$ for "relatively small" n and are not transitive as a permutation group over $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$.
I am looking for precisely such examples, which are ideally not k-transitive on any other object/ set either for $k\geq2$.
This is my very first question here so If you find anything to make this post more clear or better formatted/ worded I'd be more than happy for helpful comments.

"which are ideally not transitive on any other object/ set" does not make sense because by Cayley's theorem every group is transitive by multiplication on its own underlying set. Intransitive projective planes certainly exist but most people seem to be more interested in transitive planes.

ohh yes valid point, as each group is transitive and even sharply-transitive on its own set.

Thm 5(T) in the cited paper says there is an STS of order 15 with no nontrivial automorphisms.
